# Format the number of decimals based on another column SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, t-sql

**Overall question:**

I have a table in my SQL Server with 3 columns (ID, Value, Decimal).
So what I want to do in theory is `SELECT` the column Value and it should be formatted to the number of decimals specified in that same row.

**What I've tried:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(18,s.Decimal), s.Value ) FROM Table s
```

and similar queries with `CAST` and `FORMAT`

**What I want:**

*Table:*

```
ID  Value        Decimal
1   500.754254   2
```

When I run the query it must return Value as '500.75'

**Extra info:**
I am displaying the result in a WPF (C#) datagrid, and if it will be easier to format there, I don't mind. I just don't know how to.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Value`?

Comment: In a comment below you state: *I am working with medical risk categories and every category has got a different number of decimals*. If I get this correctly you should not use a numeric type at all. What happens if your value is `500.756` and you get it rounded as `500.76`? I suggest to use a string type and store the part before the dot and the part behind in two different columns. Combine them only for your output...

Comment: That is a very valid point. For all calculations we are using the full value, in the table it is a [Decimal(18,6)] so what happened was it was displaying for some columns 123.120000 instead of just the required amount of decimals which is also specified.

Comment: @SalmanA it is an Int datatype

Comment: @Hancs you mean `decimal(18, 6)`? Since it is for display purposes you could use the `format` function in SQL server or format it in the application.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant Decimal(18, 6).. the column [Decimal]'s datatype is Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a presentation issue, and as such, should be handled by the presentation layer. c# have very simple ways to format the output, but as you wrote in your question, you would like to know how to do it in T-SQL - so here is one option, using `cast`, `charindex` and `left`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    [Value] decimal (18,10),
    [Decimal] int
)

INSERT INTO @T ([Value], [Decimal]) VALUES
(500.754254, 2),
(50.75636, 3),
(12345.7254, 1),
(1.424, 4)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Value, 
        [Decimal],
        LEFT(CAST([Value] As varchar(18)), CHARINDEX('.', CAST([Value] As varchar(18))) + [Decimal]) As [Left] 
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ID  Value               Decimal Left
1   500,7542540000      2       500.75
2   50,7563600000       3       50.756
3   12345,7254000000    1       12345.7
4   1,4240000000        4       1.4240
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `FORMAT` here:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.123456, '##.' + LEFT('##########', Decimal))
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The trick above is that the width of the decimal component of the mask is determined by the value of the `Decimal` column.  If you expect to need more than 10 decimal places, then just widen the `###` string literal.

Another option might be using `ROUND`:

```
SELECT ROUND(Value, Decimal)
FROM yourTable;
```

However, this sort of formatting is usually best handled in your presentation layer.  So, I would probably be looking to WPF/C# for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping, it is not returning the exact answer expected but far better than I have gotten [link](https://imgur.com/Js06wCc) (see the image of result set)

Comment: Maybe I should just explain why it should show the exact decimal, I am working with medical risk categories and every category has got a different number of decimals

Comment: If you can show me what is wrong with my answer, I'm happy to edit.  Please do **not** paste a bunch of data here as comment.  Instead, maybe setup a demo and paste the link.

Comment: Check the link in my first comment. That is the result set from your query

Comment: @Hancs Your image link is not readable at all, and I don't understand what those numbers.  Check [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ce4e06da75ea412cc448c89de596d3a) to see that my first option with `FORMAT` is working.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/bg4I0mB) Updated bigger image with query and result set.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) Found a solution

Comment: Probably the issue is that `FORMAT` returns an nvarchar and you're using data as float, so just add a cast `(FORMAT(123.123456, '##.' + LEFT('##########', Decimal)) as float)`

Comment: @DDS I still don't see what the issue is.  But thanks for the comment.